# Tracing linked libraries

Tags: linux, debugging, shared-libraries, ldd

I'm getting some errors which make me think that my Linux program isn't linking to the libraries it's supposed to. How can I get the full path to all linked libraries? I know `ldd` will give me the names, but how can I use that to get the full path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually `ldd` gives you absolute path with filename of whatever from your application's shared library dependencies it's able to find.

```
    $ ldd v8test 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb78b2000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb787e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb7875000)
    libcppunit-1.12.so.1 => /usr/lib/libcppunit-1.12.so.1 (0xb782c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb7604000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb75dd000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb75bf000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7478000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb745f000)
    libboost_system-mt.so.1.38.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so.1.38.0 (0xb745b000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb78b3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb7456000)
    libboost_thread-mt.so.1.38.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.38.0 (0xb7383000)
    libboost_filesystem-mt.so.1.38.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.1.38.0 (0xb7370000)
    libtinyxml.so.1 => /home/dmitry/tinyxml/libtinyxml.so.1 (0xb7359000)
    libboost_regex-mt.so.1.38.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt.so.1.38.0 (0xb728c000)
    libmysqlclient_r.so.15 => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.15 (0xb70a1000)
    libicuuc.so.42 => /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.42 (0xb6f61000)
    libicudata.so.42 => /usr/lib/libicudata.so.42 (0xb601a000)
    libicui18n.so.42 => /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.42 (0xb5e6b000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/libcrypt.so.1 (0xb5e39000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/libnsl.so.1 (0xb5e22000)
```

The libraries are searched by its soname (e.g. libboost_filesystem-mt.so.1.38.0) in paths mentioned in `/etc/ld.so.conf`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or set with `rpath` in the binary itself.

If `ldd` is unable to find something it will look like

```
    libicuuc.so.42 => not found
```

In this case consider using one of the mentioned ways to give correct search path.

`ldd` will warn you when it's unable to load the library due to some reason.

```
$ ldd v8test 
./v8test: error while loading shared libraries: /home/dmitry/a/liba.so.2: invalid ELF header
```

Of course it can't protect you from the errors in the library itself. In fact it's possible your application to depend on libraries A and B, both depending on incompatible versions on some library C. In this situation your program has a good chance to crash (unless library C doesn't have [symbol versioning](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/symversion.html)) - ldd is not going to warn you, but you should be able to see it in the output.

[Program-Library-HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) will be useful for you.

Check also some options of `ldd` or [dynamic linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker).

Comment: If I know that some code at around 0x2F48D76B is broken, does ldd output rule out the possibility that it is a broken library?